# How to add the XML declaration?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I tried to make a XML declaration below:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"? ?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?
```

with `createDeclaration` method I send a different argument for pydev. But what's the VB.NET syntax for that?

Comment: Please could you post a small snippet of code that you've tried? - we don't know what technology you're using (xmldocument, xelement, etc)...

Comment: Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

        Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration

        xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing)

 doc.AppendChild(xmldecl)